How to exit app when back button is pressed and drawer is opened?
The goal is to ensure that when the drawer is open and on pressing the back button should exit the app instead of closing the drawer. However, the issue is that the BackHandler is triggering even when the drawer is not open.
const isDrawerOpen = useDrawerStatus()

useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Drawer opne status : ", isDrawerOpen)
}, [isDrawerOpen])


const backAction = () => {
    console.log("BackAction")
    if (true) {
    // if (isDrawerOpen === 'open') {
        console.log("DRAWER IS OPEN")
        BackHandler.exitApp();
        return true;
    }
    return false; 
};

useEffect(() => {
    const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
        'hardwareBackPress',
        backAction
    );
    return () => backHandler.remove();
}, [isDrawerOpen]); 

I also tried using a true condition, meaning the app should exit on back press regardless of the drawer's status, but even then, when the drawer is open, pressing the back button still closes the drawer instead of exiting the app.

could you share the useDrawerStatus hook code?

@HugoGresse useDrawerStatus is inbuilt hook in react-navigation
